# Error creating multi staged Dockerfile for react app

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, webpack

Trying to create a production ready image of my react app and looking at articles online it seems a multi staged build is the way to go. Never done a multi stage build before (didn't even know they existed up until 20 mins ago tbh).
But was following [this](https://rsbh.dev/blog/dockerize-react-app) article and in my own setup I have a Dockerfile like;

```
FROM node:14-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile
COPY . .
RUN yarn build

FROM nginx:1.19-alpine
COPY --from=build ./app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

When I try to build it on the CLI I get the following error;

```
 => ERROR [stage-1 2/2] COPY --from=build ./app/build /usr/share/nginx/html     
------
 > [stage-1 2/2] COPY --from=build ./app/build /usr/share/nginx/html:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/app/build" not found: not found
```

Not sure where to turn from here. Any clarity would be great.

**Extra info**

I am running my app with a custom webpack setup and have the following scripts in my package.json;

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development .",
    "build": "webpack --mode production ."
  },
```

Can provide the webpack config if required

Comment: Dockerfile looking good, could you provide the webpack config? and which command do you run docker build?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in the COPY instruction: the source path should not start with a dot.

`COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html`

Multi staged builds allow to use temporary containers to do preparatory tasks, then you can copy out artifacts from them, but path structure should be respected

Comment: Tried it without the . and had it like you said but it produced the exact same result - failed to compute cache key: "/app/build" not found: not found